# Flutter Web: first screen loading

Tags: flutter, splash-screen, flutter-web

It takes 10 seconds for him to be on the splash page.
How to optimize the first screen loading speed of Flutter on the web platform?

Comment: Can you provide more info as to what is happening in your app? Some code samples and explanation of how you're running your app. For debug mode it takes a while to load with the JIT compiler for dart to JS. In release mode it'll load much faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If you're using an image on the first page, it might take some time to load if that image is a high-resolution one. So try to reduce the
  image quality and reduce the image size.
- Use this link for flutter performance best practices - https://flutter.dev/docs/perf/rendering/best-practices